# How to add index signature in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, index-signature

I am trying to use reduce with Typescript to reach a total count of incoming messages. I'm confused on how to add an index signature. I keep getting the error: " Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature." on variables newArray and counts[k]. I have read through several similar questions but have not figured out how to apply them to my specific scenario. I am new to JavaScript and TypeScript.

Here is my array:

```
        var data = [
        { time: '9:54' }, 
        { time: '9:54' },
        { time: '9:54' },
        { time: '9:55' }, 
        { time: '9:55' },
        { time: '9:55' },
        { time: '9:55' },
        { time: '9:56' }, 
        { time: '9:56' },
        { time: '9:56' },
        { time: '9:56' },
        { time: '9:57' }, 
        { time: '9:57' },
        { time: '9:57' },
        { time: '9:57' },
        { time: '9:57' }
    ];
```

This is how I need my array for use in a rechart graph:

```
        var dataWithCounts = [
        { time: '9:54', messages: 3 }, 
        { time: '9:55', messages: 4 }, 
        { time: '9:56', messages: 4 }, 
        { time: '9:57', messages: 5 }
    ];
```

With the help of 'Just a Student's' answer from this Stack Overflow question: [Group and count values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387647/group-and-count-values-in-an-array)
, I have the following.

```
        var counts = data.reduce((newArray, item) => {
           let time = item.time;
           if (!newArray.hasOwnProperty(time)) {
               newArray[time] = 0;
           } 
           newArray[time]++;
           return newArray;
        }, {});

        console.log(counts);

        var countsExtended = Object.keys(counts).map(k => {
           return { time: k, messages: counts[k] };
       });

       console.log(countsExtended);
```

Where and how do I declare an index signature? Below are various things I've tried.

- `let newArray: { [time: string] };` and receive a duplicate identifier error.
- adding string to the parameter `var counts = data.reduce((newA:string, item)` gives me an error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'."
- adding `newA[time].toString()`gives me errors, "The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access."

Comment: Not a typescript guy but would guess that it's because you don't declare the third and fourth arguments to the `reduce` callback. The function you pass to `reduce` gets 1. The accumulator. 2. The current item in the array. 3. The current index. 4. The original array.

Comment: Set `noImplicitAny` to false in your tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The type of your accumulator in the `.reduce` call is almost certainly the issue. Since it is just given as `{}`, that's what its type is inferred as, and the type `{}` doesn't have an index signature. You can fix this by casting your initial value so that it does include a signature:

```
var counts = data.reduce((newArray, item) => {
    let time = item.time;
    if (!newArray.hasOwnProperty(time)) {
        newArray[time] = 0;
    } 
    newArray[time]++;
    return newArray;
}, {} as {[key: string]: any}); // <-- note the cast here
```

I gave the index signature type `any`, but you may want to make it something more specific for your particular case.

Answer (score 5):

The correct types for your array would be:

```
Array<{time: string}>
```

or:

```
{time: string}[]
```

or:

```
{[key: number]: {time: string}}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Answer to Original Question

The main caveat was that the `reduce` accumulator value was not properly typed.

Original code:

```
const result = data.reduce(someLogicCallback, {})
```

Need to do in the following way:

```
const accumulator: {[key: string]: number} = {}
const result = data.reduce(someLogicCallback, accumulator)
```

### Other Possible Caveats

This part might be helpful for the later occasional googlers.

I came up here looking to solve a similar issue, but in my case I had an object with an already predefined type

```
typeof someObject // predefinedType

type predefinedType = {
  someKey: number;
  otherKey: number;
}
```

and I got `index signature is missing in type predefinedType` error when I tried to extract entries from that object

```
const entries = Object.entries<number>(someObject);
```

The obvious solution was to do the type assertion

```
type TypedIndexObj = {[key: string]: number}
const entries = Object.entries<number>(someObject as TypedIndexObj);
```

But this would be too restrictive because it will always assert values types of `someObject` as `number` which might change over time.

The best way of adding index type of such an object that I came up with is to use `keyof` syntax

```
type TypedIndexObj = {[key in keyof typeof someObject]:(typeof someObject)[key]}
const entries = Object.entries<number>(someObject as TypedIndexObj);
```

### Reference: Corrected Code from the Original Question

Here is the fully typed corrected version of the code from the original question:

```
const accumulator: {[key: string]: number} = {}

const counts = data.reduce((_accumulator, item) => {
  const time = item.time;
  // no error on the next line
  if (!_accumulator.hasOwnProperty(time)) {
      _accumulator[time] = 0;
  } 
  _accumulator[time]++;
  return _accumulator;
}, accumulator);

const countsExtended = Object.keys(counts).map(k => {
    return { time: k, messages: counts[k] };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you, you need to create the interface for the object...

```
interface counts_t{
    time?: string,
    messages?: number
}

var data: counts_t[] = [
    { time: '9:54' }, 
    { time: '9:55' }, 
    { time: '9:56' }, 
    { time: '9:57' }
];

    var counts = data.reduce((newArray:counts_t, item:counts_t) => {
       let time = item.time;
       if (!newArray.hasOwnProperty(time)) {
           newArray[time] = 0;
       } 
       newArray[time]++;
       return newArray;
    }, {});

    console.log(counts);

    var countsExtended: counts_t[] = Object.keys(counts).map(k => {
       return { time: k, messages: counts[k] };
    });

   console.log(countsExtended);
```

Comment: Thanks 'I wrestled a bear once'. That may be another way to solve it. CRice's answer above worked. Awesome username btw

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a type that has an index signature. Ex.

```
const myObj: {[key: string]: string} = {
  someProperty: 'someValue',
};
```

The `{[key: string]: any}` is telling Typescript that this obj has an index signature of type string.