# How can I group an array and get count of all the records having similar type/org

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an `array` `orglist` with field `organization`. In the same array or new I need count of all the org present.

This is my array

```
{
    "orgId": 56,
    "org": "EDC",
    "Id": 816,
},
{
    "orgId": 37,
    "org": "EDC",
    "Id": 85425,
},
{
    "orgId": 68,
    "org": "AXC",
    "Id": 85427,
},
{
    "orgId": 28,
    "org": "SEE",
    "Id": 858,
}
```

I am looking for this output

```
{
    "orgId": 56,
    "org": "EDC",
    "Id": 816,
    "orgCount":"2"
    
},
{
    "orgId": 37,
    "org": "EDC",
    "Id": 85425,
    "orgCount":"2"
},
{
    "orgId": 68,
    "org": "AXC",
    "Id": 85427,
    "orgCount":"1"
},
....
```

I tried below solution but that provide me only `count` and `org` value and excluding all other fields

```
var counts = this.orglist.reduce((p, c) => {
var name = c.org;
if (!p.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
p[name] = 0;
}
p[name]++;
return p;
}, {});
```

How can I get expected output?

Comment: So to clarify, you want to group by the `org` key, get the `orgId` and `Id` of the first match and have `orgCount` be the number of values with the same `orgId`?

Comment: For context, this was linked from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387859).

Comment: @Justastudent - I am looking for extra field count based on org. As I added desired output.

Comment: Search for _"javascript array of objects group by key"_ and then just add the amount to every element in your array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is a two-stage process, first to count the occurrences of each `org` value, and then to add that property to the input objects:

```js
let orglist = [{
    "orgId": 56,
    "org": "EDC",
    "Id": 816,
},
{
    "orgId": 37,
    "org": "EDC",
    "Id": 85425,
},
{
    "orgId": 68,
    "org": "AXC",
    "Id": 85427,
},
{
    "orgId": 28,
    "org": "SEE",
    "Id": 858,
}];

const counts = orglist.reduce((c, o) => {
   c[o.org] = c[o.org] || 0;
   c[o.org]++;
   return c;
}, {});

orglist = orglist.map(({org, ...rest}) => ({ ...rest, org, "orgCount" : counts[org] }));

console.log(orglist);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
const output = orgList.map((org1) => ({
  ...org1,
  orgCount: orgList.filter(org2 => org2.org === org1.org).length
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map` to add `orgCount` to each element using the `counts` object you have:

```js
const orglist = [
  { "orgId": 56, "org": "EDC", "Id": 816 },
  { "orgId": 37, "org": "EDC", "Id": 85425 }, 
  { "orgId": 68, "org": "AXC", "Id": 85427 },
  { "orgId": 28, "org": "SEE", "Id": 858 }
];

const counts = orglist.reduce((p, c) => {
  var name = c.org;
  if (!p.hasOwnProperty(name)) p[name] = 0;
  p[name]++;
  return p;
}, {});

const res = orglist.map(e => ({...e, orgCount: counts[e.org]}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
const arr = [{
    "orgId": 56,
    "org": "EDC",
    "Id": 816,
  },
  {
    "orgId": 37,
    "org": "EDC",
    "Id": 85425,
  },
  {
    "orgId": 68,
    "org": "AXC",
    "Id": 85427,
  },
  {
    "orgId": 28,
    "org": "SEE",
    "Id": 858,
  }
];

const response = Object.values(arr.reduce((res, el) => {
  const count = res[el.org]?.orgCount || 0
  const item = {...(res[el.org] || el), ...{orgCount: count + 1}}
  res[el.org] = item
  return res
}, {}))
console.log(response)
```